# Visual studio setup project - problem with the generated installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

im having trouble making an installer for my project, i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fehVTLNQorQ , when i build the setup project in the output console i only get this

```
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Setup' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup' completed ------
1>------ Build started: Project: Setup, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\Users\Juan Finol\source\repos\Win-cloudmetadrive\Setup\Debug\Setup.msi'...
WARNING: Including primary output of project 'CloudMetaPrinter.csproj' with target framework '.NETCoreApp v3.1' may result in incomplete content. See here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2112157
Packaging file 'CloudMetaPrinter.runtimeconfig.json'...
Packaging file 'CloudMetaPrinter.dll'...
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and when i install the project the shortcut is a .ink, if i try to run it i get a message that says its a dll file and can damage my system, if i go to the installation folder i only see a folder names Setup and inside is only a .dll file and a .runtimeconfig.json file, i tried to look for other tutorials but all are the same and i didn't find a solution for the problem.

Sorry for my english and thanks for the help!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED!

> Adding new support .NET Core 3 scenarios. The output of .NET Core 3 projects should be consumed using "PublishItemsOutputGroup" instead of "Primary Output". There's also a new "PublishProfilePath" field in the properties window when "PublishItemsOutputGroup" is selected which allows for the creation of self contained .NET Core 3 installers. More details to come.

i was using "Primary Output" instead of "PublishItemsOutputGroup"
Source: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects